# Why @uirouter/core not install duding installation on @uirouter.angularjs?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I update to last version 1.0.11 in package.json :

```
"@uirouter/angularjs": "1.0.11",
```

and try to bundle js libs with `webpack` :

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-material';
import '@uirouter/angularjs';
```

. here is the error :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/ui-router-angularjs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@uirouter/core' in 'D:\myproject\node_modules\@uirouter\angularjs\release'
 @ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/ui-router-angularjs.js 9:101-126
```

In the previous vesrion i had a folder in node_modules folder , but in new version not created.
Is there any breaking changes in this release?

Answer (score 0):

It's appears with the migration to the latest `ui-router` version

try the next commands

`npm cache verify`

`npm prune`

`npm install`

Comment: Typo @OuP - npm cache verify, not npm cashe verify